# R: Loop over list of data frames and create plot of columns with constraints

Tags: r, loops, plot

I want to loop over a list of numeric data frames and create plots for specific columns of each data frame using a for loop. I have a working code but the result is odd. I would expect only two plots to be created but R creates four and I can simply not understand why especially because when I use print instead of plot, he is printing the values I would expect. Below a small example of the much bigger dataset. Any idea is much appreciated. Many thanks!

```
# Create data
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
c <- c(0,0,0,1,0)

d <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
e <- c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
f <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)

# Create data frames
df1 <- data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
df2 <- data.frame(cbind(d,e,f))
names(df2) <- c("a","b","c")

# Create list of data frames
l <- list(df1,df2)

# Create titles for plots
titlenames <- c("Graph 1","Graph 2")

# Loop over list of data frames and create plots
for (i in l){ for(j in titlenames) {
  plot(x=(i$a[i$c==0]),y=(i$b[i$c==0]),main="",xlab="",ylab="")
  title(main=paste(j))
}}
```

Comment: `for (i in l){ for(j in titlenames)...` 2 x 2 = 4

Comment: Wow, now I get it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should you be doing something like this? -

```
# Loop over list of data frames and create plots
for (i in seq(titlenames)) {
  plot(x=(l[[i]]$a[l[[i]]$c==0]),y=(l[[i]]$b[l[[i]]$c==0]),main="",xlab="",ylab="")
  title(main=titlenames[i])
}
```

I posted as answer, the comment would be ugly and hard to read. Basically, I've removed the j loop and am tracking everything with 1 which now loops over 1:n, and not `l`.

Comment: I understand the problem. Although your solution is right I think it's now looping through titlenames which is a vector independent of the list of data frames. Still with your example and Stephen Henderson's comment I can reconstruct it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: nothing like this or your above code will work if your data.frames in your list have different column names e.g.abc & def

Comment: Yes, in fact for the big data set I work with indexing but I figured it's easier to work with names in the example. Thanks!